# Too many elements when initialize hashmap

Tags: scala, hashmap

When I set immutable hashmap contents on initialization like this:

```
var result_tags=HashMap[String,Int]()
    result_tags=("video"->0,"game"->0,"news"->0,"ee"->0,"sport"->0,
  "shop"->0,"ju"->0,"story"->0,"pho"->0,"con"->0,"live"->0,"life"->0,"soft"->0,"hire"->0,"car"->0,
  "mm"->0,"mus"->0,"mob"->0,"male"->0,"heal"->0, "sca"->0,"bank"->0,"mail"->0,"cool"->0,"pict"->0, "dl"->0)
```

It gives me the error:

```
too many elements for tuple:26,allowed:22
```

It means the max number of tuples is 22. I know `->` is for creating tuples. Is there other ways to initialize hashmap without the limit number of its elements.

Answer (score 7):

What you're actually doing there is initializing a giant `Tuple` type and trying to assign it to the `result_tags` variable which is of type `HashMap`, which wouldn't work even if the tuple size wouldn't exceed 
maximum size.

So the error you get regarding tuples is not referring to the `->` syntax that you use, but to the number of elements inside the `(...)` list. You would get the same error even if you wrote it like this:

```
(("video", 0), ("game", 0), ..., ("dl", 0))
```

Second, in your case you should do:

```
var result_tags = HashMap("video" -> 0, "game" -> 0, ..., "dl" -> 0)
```

(notice that I omitted the type info because Scala infers the type for you.)

The `(a1, a2, ..., aN)` syntax is an entirely different thing in Scala, since it initializes a tuple type. Every such declaration is converted into a `TupleN` type, where the maximum size is 22. So the Scala library actually has 22 distinct `Tuple` classes from `Tuple1` to `Tuple22`.

Third, your style could use some corrections

- You should prefer the immutable version of map which is `scala.collection.Map`
- You should prefer immutable variables, which means `val` instead of `var`
- And less important, but variable names are preferred to be camelCased, so that would be `resultTags`

Answer (score 1):

Just

```
var result_tags = Map("video"->0,"game"->0,"news"->0,"ee"->0,"sport"->0,
  "shop"->0,"ju"->0,"story"->0,"pho"->0,"con"->0,"live"->0,"life"->0,"soft"->0,"hire"->0,"car"->0,
  "mm"->0,"mus"->0,"mob"->0,"male"->0,"heal"->0, "sca"->0,"bank"->0,"mail"->0,"cool"->0,"pict"->0, "dl"->0)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you initialise the Map in Scala

Map initialisation

```
import scala.collection.immutable.Map

val result_tags = Map("video" -> 0, "game" -> 0, "news" -> 0, "ee" -> 0, "sport" -> 0,
      "shop" -> 0, "ju" -> 0, "story" -> 0, "pho" -> 0, "con" -> 0, "live" -> 0, "life" -> 0, "soft" -> 0, "hire" -> 0, "car" -> 0,
      "mm" -> 0, "mus" -> 0, "mob" -> 0, "male" -> 0, "heal" -> 0, "sca" -> 0, "bank" -> 0, "mail" -> 0, "cool" -> 0, "pict" -> 0, "dl" -> 0)
```

HashMap initialisation

```
import scala.collection.immutable.HashMap

val result_tags = HashMap("video" -> 0, "game" -> 0, "news" -> 0, "ee" -> 0, "sport" -> 0,
      "shop" -> 0, "ju" -> 0, "story" -> 0, "pho" -> 0, "con" -> 0, "live" -> 0, "life" -> 0, "soft" -> 0, "hire" -> 0, "car" -> 0,
      "mm" -> 0, "mus" -> 0, "mob" -> 0, "male" -> 0, "heal" -> 0, "sca" -> 0, "bank" -> 0, "mail" -> 0, "cool" -> 0, "pict" -> 0, "dl" -> 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the `+` method in the immutable.HashMap class to achieve what you were trying to do:

From the scala doc:

```
def +[B1 >: B](elem1: (A, B1), elem2: (A, B1), elems: (A, B1)*): HashMap[A, B1]

Adds two or more elements to this collection and returns a new collection.


val result_tags = HashMap[String,Int]()

val result_tags_filled = result_tags + ("video"->0,"game"->0,"news"->0,"ee"->0,"sport"->0,
  "shop"->0,"ju"->0,"story"->0,"pho"->0,"con"->0,"live"->0,"life"->0,"soft"->0,"hire"->0,"car"->0,
  "mm"->0,"mus"->0,"mob"->0,"male"->0,"heal"->0, "sca"->0,"bank"->0,"mail"->0,"cool"->0,"pict"->0, "dl"->0)
```